# How to convert the normal text to bold text?

Tags: dialog, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I have this code in my `Dialog`:

```
//other code
dialog.addText(strFmt("Delete this field's value: %1?", MyTable.FieldTable));
//other code
```

I have an output looklike:

[image: I have an output looklike]

I know the `strUpr` function:

```
dialog.addText(strFmt("Delete this field's value: %1?", strUpr(MyTable.FieldTable)));
```

Does there exist a method or function to convert only the *FIELDValue* to **bold text**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the [`bold`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/formbuildstatictextcontrol.bold.aspx) property to `7` on [*FormBuildStaticTextControl*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/formbuildstatictextcontrol.aspx).

Control can be obtained via the [`control`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dialogcontrol.control.aspx) method on `DialogText` returned by `addText` method.

> The integer that is returned contains the weight of the font as follows:
>
> ```
> 0 Use the default font weight. 
> 1 Thin. 
> 2 Extra-light. 
> 3 Light. 
> 4 Normal. 
> 5 Medium. 
> 6 Semibold. 
> 7 Bold. 
> 8 Extra-bold. 
> 9 Heavy.
> ```

Example:

```cs
Dialog dialog = new Dialog();
DialogText dt = dialog.addText("Test");
FormBuildStaticTextControl txtCtl = dt.control();
txtCtl.bold(7);

dialog.run();
```

Comment: Great thanks @Matej! It's possible to convert to bold text only part the text?
Look like my example? I'm grateful!

Comment: Just use `addField` instead, then make the field non-editable.

Comment: @ulisses with text (FormBuildStaticTextControl) you can't mix format. Maybe you could use HTML (custom `DialogControl` with `FormControlType::HTML`). It will be easier with custom form than customizing `Dialog`.

Comment: @Matej .Thaks for your time.  Very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

A working example using `addFieldValue` (similar to Matej's solution):

```cpp
Dialog dialog = new Dialog("Dialog example");
DialogField f1 = dialog.addFieldValue(extendedTypeStr(String30), 'Value', "Delete this field's value?");
FormBuildStringControl c1 = f1.control();
c1.allowEdit(false);
c1.skip(true);
c1.bold(7);
c1.viewEditMode(ViewEditMode::View);
dialog.run();
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that `Dialog` class has the ability to display **bold** text, at least I haven't seen such, neither did I find any method to format text in a dialog. One solution would be to create custom form that looks like a dialog box, but I think it is redundant.

Regarding uppercase, you can use `strUpr` ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa880106.aspx)) method:

```
//other code
dialog.addText(strUpr(strFmt("Delete this field's value: %1?", MyTable.FieldTable)));
//other code
```

Comment: Thanks @Maxim Lazarev ,I've seen that function. For me It's very good if I can have the bold text. I appreciate your advice.